# Averaging parameters in a host before sending it out to parameter servers

Tags: tensorflow

I'm writing code to run distributed synchronous training in a cluster with 32 hosts each having 16 GPUs.

I read this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/distributed/index.html and this sample code: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception

Both seem to suggest running a worker per GPU and using SyncReplicaOptimizer to run the synchronous training.

If I do that, after every step, each PS will receive gradients for a subset of parameters from 32*16 workers, correct?

Is it possible to average the gradients from 16 GPUs in each host before sending the averaged gradients to the parameter servers? This way each PS will only have to receive 32 set of gradients instead of 32*16.

If it is possible to do this, is there sample code somewhere on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do, official `cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py` example shows how to average gradients computed on multiple GPUs and save them in RAM on a single host. You could then combine it with sync_replicas to take in-RAM variables and aggregate them together between hosts